# copying .tar.gz file while writing it

Tags: unix, tar, scp, corrupt, md5sum

Is writing a `.tar.gz` file purely sequential?

When copying a large file, I started compressing it, and while it was compressing, `scp`ing it to a different machine. Afterwards I checked the `md5sum` on both machines, and they did not match. I guess it wasn't the best idea ever to start reading the `.tar.gz` before it was finished. I supposed that writing that `.tar.gz` file would only append to the end so that reading it would work out fine.

Does anybody know anything about the mechanics of this? What specifically is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were doing to scp with a simple `.tar` file, it could work.

`tar` is a sequential archiving tool mostly designed to be piped to `cpio` to write on a tape.

But here, you ask `tar` to first create the archive and then compress it. The compression can happen only after the archive is finished.